# How can I access raw touch capacitive images from an Android phone?

Tags: java, android, flutter, touch, touchscreen

I found an example:http://huyle.de/blog/capacitive-images/. Is there a way to access raw capacitive images on multiple Android phones? How should I modify the kernel to get the raw input data and then generate the capacitive image? I have no Android hardware or kernel development experience. Any better suggestions? Thank you very much for answering it for me。

I want to get the raw input data of the touch screen and generate a capacitive image

[capacitive images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQS4q.png)

Comment: Not on a random device.  It's possible if you're rooted, but that's all.  Although if you look at TouchEvent, you can get a lot more data than the clicks people generally use.